# Open CV or alternative for post processing identification

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm new to Open CV and image processing, but I was wondering if I have a still image, say a jpeg file is it possible to run Open CV or another package on the image and have it identify where the humans are in the image? (I don't know if that sounds impossible or not since I haven't worked much in this but any advice would be appreciated) The photos are from the raspberry pi, which takes a photo after a PIR motion scanner detects movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use opencv for this. Opencv [Hog descriptor](http://chrisjmccormick.wordpress.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/) may help you for this. Opencv can be used in [rasberry pi](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/) as well.

Here is the link for the [people detection code](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/peopledetect.cpp?rev=1772), or you can find it in samples of the opencv package.

Comment: This is what you have expected or something different?

Comment: I think that will work, going to work on it this weekend. Because I've noticed using PIR it sometimes detects the change it light or something environmentally related so using that I should be able to forward my PIR image to a server and have it check before alerting me to movement.